# FFMPEG select highest bitrage input stream of hls m3u8 file

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I am attempting to use ffmpeg to record an HLS Livestream, described by input.m3u8.  input.m3u8 contains a number of different bitrate streams: input_01.m3u8, input_02.m3u8, ...; which contain the actual mpeg-ts segmented video files.  Frequently the number and quality of the available streams varies.  I am trying to make this an automated process so that my co-workers can use it, but I need ffmpeg to always select the best available stream from the input.m3u8 file.  Can anybody point me in the right direction on this?

Currently I use:

```
ffmpeg -n -i "http://path/input_0x.m3u8" -c copy "%path%\%FileName%
```

where %path% and %filename% are defined by the batch file calling ffmpeg and I manually look up the best bitrate stream.

Comment: FFmpeg's own HLS demuxer don't do this. You can use yt-dl with `-f best` and `--get-url` and pass the result to ffmpeg.

Comment: Thanks! That worked.